# nowhere $0$ vector field on $\mathbb{R}$ such that integral curves can be defined only on neighborhood of $0$

Tags: smooth-manifolds

This is question 2 from Spivak Vol 1. Chapter 5:

Find a nowhere $0$ vector field on $\mathbb{R}$ such that all integral curves can be defined only on some interval around $0$.

I don't quite understand what the question is asking...

Is $x \mapsto (x^2 + 1)\partial /\partial x$, with integral curve $t \mapsto t^3/3 + x$ a solution?

Comment: You'd better review how to solve basic ODE. What is the ODE that this vector field gives you?

Comment: @TedShifrin You are right.... Is it $c'(t) = f(c(t)) = c(t)^2 + 1$?

Comment: Yes. And now the solutions ... ?

Comment: c(t) = tan (t)?

Comment: That's the integral curve with initial condition $c(0)=0$. Generally?

Comment: c(t) = tan(t + c). And it still is a solution to this question?

Comment: Well, what do you think?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, because it clearly went through all points.

Comment: I do not understand your comment.

Comment: Because the image of the map $c(t) = \tan(t)$ is the whole $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: That is not relevant. What did the question ask?

Comment: Well, that is exactly why I ask this question here: I don't know what the author means by: can be defined only on some interval around 0. I interpret it as all integral curve must contain a neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: The function $c(t)$ (for some particular initial condition) is only defined for $t$ in some interval $(-\delta,\delta)$, not for all $t$.

Comment: Sorry, I am even more confused, can you explain what is the question asking? and maybe a hint on how to approach it?